# Where is the Contract Board in Vergen?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I found the Contract Board in Flotsam easily enough -- it's right next to the Inn.

But now that I've reached Vergen, I've been looking for a new contract board, and haven't yet had much luck. Does Vergen have a contract board? I have a feeling it's hiding right in front of my eyes...

Comment: [Looks like it has one](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/975399-the-witcher-2-assassins-of-kings/59167237), trying to find info on where ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The board *is* by the inn, to the right of the door, closer to the stairwell down to the Inn itself, rather than the door leading downwards to the Inn proper.